# When should I run an OPTIMIZE on MYSQL ISAM table

Tags: mysql

We have a table with 160 columns of data, with ~31 million rows. I realize this is a lot of columns and should be redesigned, but until that pain point is reached:

```
CREATE TABLE `cdp_datacst` (
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cdp_cstunqkey` (`data1`,`data2`,`data3`,`data4`,`data5`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=185060677 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

We perform a DELETE every day and an OPTIMIZEat the end of the week.
I was wondering if there are some guideline to when an optimize should be performed.

Is a 10% change (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) benefit from an optimize.  Is there a guideline for the % Change or is this just based on the duration of the OPTIMIZE and the user's experience?

Comment: 160 columns?  Yikes, sounds like a maintenance nightmare.   I would think this question would have to do with how many rows are added and deleted each week.

Comment: @Devon About 1% gets inserted/deleted a day.  We are trying to re-organize the DB and columns but "On the RoadMap" so I'm told.